# Specifying different output directory, with random filename - UglifyJS with Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, uglifyjs

I know that I can have it output a custom file with the example below, but what if I want it to go to `js/compile/<randomfilename>.js`? I wasn't able to find any documentation where it explains that. I know that if we leave the output parameter out, it will just create a random named JS file under `js/`.

```
{% javascripts 
    'vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'
    'https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js'
    'vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    'js/app/*'
    'js/app/services/*'
    'js/app/directives/*'
    'js/app/controllers/*'
    filter='?uglifyjs2'
    output='js/app.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: I can't answer directly, but as a workaround you can eventually keep `output='js/compile/app.js'` and bust cache using [`assets_version`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#ref-framework-assets-version).

Comment: I figured it out - check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. The secret was to set it up via Assetic.

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    node: "%node_path%"
    write_to: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/static/
```

Adding the `write_to` line did it. So the files get written into `static/` now. There was another change that had to be made though, because that didn't actually change what the `asset_url` displays, only the place that assetic writes the generated files (kinda silly, I know).

I had to add this bit of config as well:

```
framework:
    templating:
        packages:
            assetic:
                base_urls: static/
```

That creates a new package called `assetic`, which defines the `base_urls`. And now we have to tell it to use that package, and also remove the output.

```
{% javascripts package='assetic'
    'vendor/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'
    'https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js'
    'vendor/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    'js/app/*'
    'js/app/services/*'
    'js/app/directives/*'
    'js/app/controllers/*'
    filter='?uglifyjs2'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```